# How to replace CKEditor CDN by yarn installed in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, webpacker

I have a Rails 6 app integrated with CKEditor Gem well.

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

But I got a request that I need to replace the CDN to internal host, so I tried install CKEditor by  `yarn add ckeditor`, and it's success.

When I go to the page have editor, the `CKEDITOR` exist in browser console, but have following error

```
root/edit_url/lang/ja.js?t=N2MA (404 Not found)
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'dir')
root/edit_url/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=N2MA (404 Not found)
```

I notice that in html head part, these two line appear unexpectedly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:3000/post/post-id/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=N2MA">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/post/post-id/lang/ja.js?t=N2MA"></script>
```

But I think it should also looking from `application.js` and `application.css` files.

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue? Thanks.

I think it's kind of path issue, but I tried many different `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` doesn't solve.